# make: *** [Makefile:2026: .] Error 2 during Kernel 6.4.3 compilation

Tags: kernel

I am trying to compile kernel-6.4.3 on Ubuntu 23.04 and I am receiving following error message no meter how I will configure kernel.

```
Must remake target 'kernel/'.
Need a job token; we don't have children
Successfully remade target file 'kernel/'.
Reaping winning child 0x55de9c49f220 PID 4049603
Removing child 0x55de9c49f220 PID 4049603 from chain.
Reaping losing child 0x55d945e87d90 PID 4049461
make: *** [Makefile:2026: .] Error 2
```

Steps to reproduce:

```
tar -zxf linux-6.4.3.tar.xz
chown user:user -R linux-6.4.3
cd linux-6.4.3
make menuconfig
make -j4
```

Comment: "... no meter how I will configure kernel" - But how **exactly** you have configured the kernel? Please, add details to your question post.

Comment: It means, that no matter how I will configure kernel before compilation, so in menuconfig.. I am receiving same error code: Makefile:2026, I have checked makefile and didn't find nothing suspicious around line 2026.. How to troubleshoot?